# What is meant by this statement w.r.t. swagger framework

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor, swagger-codegen

"The methods, parameters, and models description are tightly integrated into the server code, thereby maintaining the synchronization in APIs and its documentation."

Does it mean that If i make any change in my server code, then I have to make changes in yml file also? If yes, then lets say , If I am running 100 API's from my server(For example, if am using cherrypy) and if I make any change in my server code to keep yml code and API doc sync., do I need to modify yml code for all the 100 API's?

Basically, I want to know how any change in server code is handled? Is it by modifying yml files or by some other way?

Comment: What's the source of this quote?

Comment: http://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/restful-api-documentation-using-swagger-and-spring-mvc

http://udayakumarc.blogspot.in/

@Helen.. these are some sources